# Creating dialog in MainActivity and using it in fragments throughout application

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an application in which I frequently use dialogs in all my fragments.
I use dialogs in fragmetns mostly for displaying messages from server.

```
AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create(); ad.setCancelable(false); 
ad.setTitle(title); 
ad.setMessage(message);
 ad.setButton(context.getString(R.string.text), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    } });
```

Can I create this is my MainActivty and use this through all my fragments??
Please help me out.

Answer (score 3):

Create a public class as below.

```
 public class UtilsDialog {

    public static void promtDialog(Context context,String title, String message){
    AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create(); ad.setCancelable(false); 
    ad.setTitle(title); 
    ad.setMessage(message);
    ad.setButton(context.getString(R.string.text), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        } });
     ad.show();
    }

 }
```

and call promtDialog method as this in your fragments.

```
UtilsDialog.promtDialog(getActivity(), "add your title here", "add your message here");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Can u lead me on how do I set my content of my dialog dynamically in my fragment??

Comment: What did you mean by content ? I have shown how to pass title and message in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create a method like :

```
public void showAlert()
{
AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create(); ad.setCancelable(false); 
ad.setTitle(title); 
ad.setMessage(message);
 ad.setButton(context.getString(R.string.text), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    } });
}
```

and call this method wherever required like `MainActivity.showAlert();`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used it and it worked,but how do I change the content of my dialog dynamically in fragments??

Comment: You can pass your contents through the method as parameter like showAlert(String data1,String data2...) and call the method accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

```
public void showAlert(String title,String message){
  AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
  ad.create().setCancelable(true).setTitle(title).setMessage(message);
  ad.setButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    } });
}
```

call from fragment

```
((HomeActivity)getActivity()).showAlert("My title","My Message");
```